# Another noob wondering where I went wrong in Fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

I still don't quite understand the last two numbers in Fstab... I heard that one is the "dump", and "dumping" didn't sound like anything I wanted and/or needed, so I gave it a value of 0... I also read that the last digit was for some sort of a "diskchk" or something, and that the worse that could happen if I put a 0 here, is that the system wouldn't do checks for errors on that disk... I'm sure that's all wrong though...

Right now I'm having to click on both sdb1 and sdc1 just to mount them, I'm hoping for all drives to mount smoothly at startup...

```
Here's some code that might provide insight as to where I fumbled...
plex@plex-TZ68K ~ $ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for plex: 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007f670

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   256952319   128372736    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       256954366   488396799   115721217    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       471803904   488396799     8296448   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       256954368   471803903   107424768   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util        fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x47d9be29

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  2930274303  1465136128    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util   fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/sdd1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT
```

AND

```
plex@plex-TZ68K ~ $ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="7A1ED0151ECFC7F9" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="80F833A5F833987C" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="e881ffcf-37ab-43d1-b1a4-eb00581b7110" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="9f820e61-077d-4975-80eb-838c834ed7b1" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="SAVED BY GRACE" UUID="516A78EA019DAC70" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="I LOVE YOU !" UUID="543E2FD13E2FAB46" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd2: LABEL="KILLUMINATI - ONE" UUID="E46014BE6014997E" TYPE="ntfs"
```

And this is what my Fstab File looks like

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=9f820e61-077d-4975-80eb-838c834ed7b1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e881ffcf-37ab-43d1-b1a4-eb00581b7110 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID="E46014BE6014997E" /mnt/external_hdd ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
UUID="543E2FD13E2FAB46" /media/plex/I LOVE YOU ! ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
UUID="516A78EA019DAC70" /media/plex/SAVED BY GRACE ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

Many thanks to all of you who aid us recent converts...

Comment: Try eliminating spaces in the mountpoint names.

Comment: I was wondering about that... Thank you, I will try it...

Comment: Oh snap, you're a stinking genius! Or maybe I'm just a pothead... Either way, your solution was correct, and I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

`[DUMP]` is for backing up and is usually set to 0.

Keep `<pass>` 0 for ntfs3g filesystems as it is.

In your case use the escape sequence `\040` to escape spaces in mount point entries

```
UUID="543E2FD13E2FAB46" /media/plex/I\040LOVE\040YOU\040! ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
UUID="516A78EA019DAC70" /media/plex/SAVED\040BY\040GRACE ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

**Done**

Here's one of my posts on this:

[Mounting Windows Partitions in Ubuntu at Startup](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/mount-ntfs-partition-on-boot/)

Comment: Now I realized I need to set these drives up with SAMBA mount points in order for the emby server to see them... Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Actually, using the "0/40" command for the spaces is causing me problems... It did work to make fstab/ubuntu recognize the instructions and start the drives at boot, but now all of my directories within Plex, Kodi, and Emby would have to be totally redone, which is a very time consuming task... All because of a few spaces in my volume labels??? Yikes...

Comment: @ImdbTruth Did you try surrounding mount point with double quotes ?

Comment: I will try that... Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried using double quotation marks around the mount path but that didn't work, they wouldn't boot at start up...

Comment: UUID="543E2FD13E2FAB46" ""/media/plex/I0/040LOVE0/040YOU0/040!"" ntfs-3g default 0 0
UUID="516A78EA019DAC70" ""/media/plex/SAVED0/040BY0/040GRACE"" ntfs-3g default 0 0

Comment: That's what I tried...